# Windows 10: Prevent MS Edge from being pinned to the Task Bar on start up

Tags: windows-10, boot, reboot, microsoft-edge

**Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise**

When I start windows Microsoft Edge is automatically pinned to my task bar.

Despite having unpinned it before I shutdown Windows.

I did a web search which took me to an MS help forum.  It was stated to open the Task Manager and disable MS Edge on Startup...AND... disable it at some other setting that I don't have in Windows 10.  The thread was for Windows 11.

Just doing that one thing didn't work.

How can I keep MS Edge from being pinned to my task bar every single time I start Windows 10 Enterprise?

Comment: `disable MS Edge on Startup` is to support an entirely different function than having edge pinned on the taskbar.  Is this system connected to an AD domain?

Comment: What is an AD domain?

Comment: [Active Directory domain](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+an+ad+domain)

Comment: Thank you.  I do not know if it is in an AD domain.  It is a corporate laptop with all sorts of controls on it.

Comment: Ask someone who can answer that question, if they say. “Yes”, then they can also help solve the behavior you describe

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
2. Open LayoutModification.xml,
3. Remove this tag:

   <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Edge.lnk" />

Comment: Worth pointing out that, one of the only ways LayoutModification.xml would contain Edge, is if an Administrator configured it that way. So you might want to verify LayoutModification.xml is not being managed by your System Administrator.